# Limiting number of simultaneous sessions per user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I need to restrict the amount of times a user can log in into the app simultaneously (For example up to 10 simultaneous logins)

But I wasn't sure how to get the active number of sessions by a user - is it even possible? To get how many active sessions a user currently have? Or because PHP's GC won't delete the session immediately it's not possible? i.e. of a user session is set to 1 hour and after 1 hour of inactivity the user is logged out is it possible to check if it's ended or not?

In this case, how can I achieve that? restricting the number of sessions per user by a set number. Or I should just limit to X number of times per given time (for example 100 times per 24 hours)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? What problem is it solving?

Comment: It was a request by the organization policy to restrict the number of logins. But maybe they meant number per given time, and not really simultaneous by amount?

Comment: Maybe. I strongly suggest clarifying that before you go any further, and clarifying the exact business purpose for doing so (people dont always have rational reasons, and/or they base it on incorrect technical assumptions!). Because this sort of thing can be a PITA, especially in a stateless web environment. It's not always simple to tell when someone has closed their browser and effectively ended their session  for example - the browser doesn't find out about that. This subject, in general, gets asked about quite a lot on here, there may also be older posts you can refer to

Comment: Thank you, I will ask again and also search. And regarding telling active sessions per user (The PHP session) - due to PHP's GC nature, it means even if a login session ended for the user it's not possible to reliably detect that? And vice-versa - if a user logged in twice from 2 different browsers, it's not possible to reliably get the number of times he is currently logged in (For example if he wants to log in the 3rd time from the phone - is it not possible to get those previous logins?)

Comment: `even if a login session ended for the user it's not possible to reliably detect that`...it depends how the session ended. If the user clicked a "logout" button which sent a request to your server to clear the session, then of course it's easy. Or if they tried to send a request after the session had timed out, then, again, the server could process that. But if they just close the browser mid-session, then the server really has no way of knowing that they did that. But the user would consider themselves to have logged out, and would be annoyed if they can't start another session soon after

Comment: `if a user logged in twice from 2 different browsers, it's not possible to reliably get the number of times he is currently logged in`...of course you could have code which records the time a user logged in and out, with the ID of that session, and/or the time they last made a request within that session, and you could use that to try and work out the number of simultaneous sessions. But again, it falls down if the user doesn't notify you that they closed the browser.

Comment: Another approach in theory could be to try and keep a websocket connection open while the user has the browser open, and treat the severing of that connection as the end of the login session - a websocket server should be able to detect that. But of course maintaining such a connection in the browser will cause server overheads, and is a lot of work to setup, and results may vary if you have non-browser front-ends. I'd guess your research might show up some more possibly workarounds etc too. But you should clarify the real business purpose first, in case there's a better way overall.

Comment: Thanks! I might then just do the other method of limiting number of connections per day. That should be more doable I think. But about the session, I have 1 missing piece of the puzzle that I don't fully understand - Even if the user didn't log out with a button, then after the set time of inactivity his session should've been over right? The problem is - that for PHP GC, the session is not surely ended, and that's why it's not possible? I mean, the session that ended doesn't have some key that I can check whether it ended or not? Or even if it does, it's not certain if it really ended?

Comment: I'm not an expert on how that mechanism works, sorry. If it was me I'd have the session expiry time (e.g. 20 minutes) in a config file, and check the last known action of the user against the current time, and see if its more than the expiry time. You could have a cron job which looks through the database and marks such login sessions as expired. I would personally do that rather than relying on internals of php which I don't fully understand and might be subject to change. But it's up to you.

Comment: `I might then just do the other method of limiting number of connections per day`...this sounds like a great way to annoy your users (think about Twitter who are in the news for doing something similar right now)...I would love to know what your organisation's rationale for such a feature is.

Comment: Yep, that's annoying I really need to ask again